# libcurl C API > POST data in chunks using 2MB buffer

Tags: c, post, buffer, libcurl, chunked-encoding

How can I post data from file (specific range, say 150-250000 bytes should be posted from file) in chunks using 2MB buffer? By default libcurl uses 16K (it cannot be changed) buffer and it's too small for video streaming.

Comment: You see this 16K limit for sending data or receiving data using `libcurl`?

Answer (score 0):

The size of libcurl's internal buffer is not limiting your transfer speed (very much). The callback will be called and allowed to send data as often as possible and you can easily send data in hundreds of megabits per second using this approach, given that you have the necessary bandwidth to the server. TCP is stream-based anyway.